Using another name in response when deserializing json in ASP.NET Core 8 Web API
We are using ASP.NET Core 8 Web API. I have read this post, but I use System.Text.Json. So it is not duplicate question.
My goals are:

read a json as a string in WEB API
then deserialize it to class FooDto and return it to clients of WEB API.

I read the following json from database as a string:
{
    "product_id": 1
}

The dto class looks like this:
public class FooDto
{
    [JsonPropertyName("product_id")]
    public long? ProductId { get; set; }
}

The code that I tried looks like this:
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<FooDto>(json);

In addition, I tried like this:
JsonSerializerOptions serializeOptions = new ()
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.SnakeCaseLower,
    WriteIndented = true
};
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<FooDto>(json, serializeOptions);

However, the result of the response of the ASP.NET Core Web API 8 method looks like this:
{
    "product_id": 1
}

But, the desired result should look like this. I mean, Web API should return the following result for clients:
{
    "productId": 1
}

Is it possible to use C# property name when deserializing json?

For your desired result, use this annotation in your class: [JsonPropertyName("productId")]. Whatever you define as an explicit annotation on the members of your class will override any naming applied by any conventions or serialization options

It's unclear to me what the exact problem is. If you use the naming attribute, it will use that name in deserialization and serialization. So, if you need two different names for in/out you can use that only for one direction.

My understanding is that you want to use the same class to deserialize {"product_id":1} from the db, but the API to return as {"productId":1}? If so, I am not sure that you can do it with a single class

"I have read the following json from database:" , "the desired result should look like this. I mean, Web API should return the following result for clients" - you may want to map your database entity to a dto (i.e. two separate classes). That way you can have two different naming conventions. That's also a very common practice and outside the naming has other advantages, too. The downside is the additional allocations, of course.

@marc_s If I use [JsonPropertyName("productId")], then the deserialised value will have value null. What I mean is FooDto.productId object will have value null. Because json has underscore: {    "product_id": 1}

@Fildor yeah, you are absolutely correct! Is it possible to create without additional model classes?

Well, I guess it would somehow but only with significant effort and it would be somewhat brittle, I guess. Simply having a model from db and then map it to a dto is probably way quicker, testable, common practice and supported by numerous nugets that automate this for you. So, I would recommend that over fiddling with direction-sensitive json conversion ...

^^ That would also be "least surprising" to fellow and/or future coders.

You still haven't achieve  read a json as a string in WEB API and make the json snake_case? I think you need share more details.

For your requirement, just remove the [JsonPropertyName] attribute and only use the following code can achieve. Also be sure you do not configure anything about Serialization/Deserialization in Program.cs:
string json = "{\r\n    \"product_id\": 1\r\n}";

JsonSerializerOptions serializeOptions = new ()
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.SnakeCaseLower,
    WriteIndented = true
};
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<FooDto>(json, serializeOptions);


I actually think having separate DB Entity and API DTO classes could be beneficial and the "common practice" thing to have here.

Thanks a lot! It works like a charm! :)
